# Use Cut delimiter to extract initial part of the string

Tags: shell, delimiter, cut

I have a variable `A` that has a value whose first part is always `DEV-UI`. Various possible values of A could be : `DEV-UI`, `DEV-UI2`, `DEV-UI*`

I would like to extract just `DEV` from it and store it in another variable. This way, the other variable `B` always has value `DEV`.

How can I extract, from `A`, `DEV` and stored in B?

I am looking for any cut delimiter or any expression that can be used to achieve this in my shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B=$(echo "$A" | cut -d'-' -f1)
```

Splits the string by `-` and returns the first part.

Answer (score 0):

The evident step is obviously just to set `B="DEV"` since you state that it is always `DEV`. However, below I show how to extract it as the first field.

It depends a bit on the type of shell you have, but if it is any form of `sh`-compatible shell you could do :

```
$ B=${A%%-*}
```

This is explained in the [POSIX shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> **`${parameter%%[word]}`**
>   Remove Largest Suffix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with the largest portion of the suffix matched by the pattern deleted.

```
$ A="hello-big-world"
$ echo ${A%-*}
hello-big
$ echo ${A%%-*}
hello
```

When using C Shell you are not in such luck :

```
% set a = "hello-big-world"
% set b = `echo $a | cut -d- -f1`
% echo $b
hello
```